# Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 not running

Tags: windows, docker

I installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit using the full installation. Git was already installed in a directory on its own but I did not deselect it for the installation. There is no error during the installation. However, when I start the Docker Quickstart Terminal it cannot find the bash.exe.

[image: Cannot fin't bash.exe]

When I then select bash.exe of the existing Git installation I get the following problem.

[image: Invalid command line]

How can I solve that?

When I start Kitematic it starts the "Setup Initialization" but cannot find a native setup. "Use Virtualbox" doesn't help either.

Comment: Can you run the Docker host vm in VirtualBox? And connect it with ssh?

Comment: I would first need to install a linux vm, right? I have tried that before but it is a company pc and I cannot connect to the network from the virtual machine.

Comment: ok thanks. I asked a counter question because I don't know on how to "run the Docker host vm in VirtualBox". Is there a command? Will I have to create a vm and run docker inside? What do I need to do?

Comment: When I install it as stated above there are no virtual machines in VirtualBox :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Correct the link (path) to bash.exe in Programs > Docker Quickstart Terminal > right click > properties
2. If you run docker behind a proxy enter the proxy in start.sh of your local docker toolbox installation, e.g. `export HTTP_PROXY="http://123.45.67.89:8080"`
3. Execute Docker Quickstart Terminal as admin: Programs > Docker Quickstart Terminal > right click > execute as admin